# Aligning button vertically in Constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have this screen and want to align the login button below the forgot password. And the forgot password button should be aligned with the edit text fields.  However, things are messed up.

[image: layout]

Here is my xml code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
    android:id="@+id/login_toolbar"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/login_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

        android:text="@string/email" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:text="Login to your Account"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_forgot_password_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="@string/forgot_pass"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_create_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp" />
```

How can I align both buttons?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your login btn xml:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/login_forgot_password_btn"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/login_forgot_password_btn"
```

and to your forgotPass btn:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textInputLayout4"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/textInputLayout4"
```